# Client call JSON result show as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, client, getjson

I have a set of json data which is generated in php with `json_decode` function, here is the results:

[image]

I then create a html document and try to call the result using jquery `$.getJSON`:

```
var apiSrc = 'http://localhost/api/ws-data';
var showData = $('#result');

$(function(){

    $.getJSON(apiSrc, function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        var items = data.blog.map(function (item) {
            return item.key + ': ' + item.value;
        });

        showData.empty();

        if(items.length) {
            var content = '<li>' + items.join('</li><li>') + '</li>';
            var list = $('<ul />').html(content);
            showData.append(list);
        }
    });

    showData.text('Loading...');
});
```

and the results for above is:

```
REST - Get JSON from PHP file on the server side

    undefined: undefined
    undefined: undefined
    undefined: undefined
    undefined: undefined
    ..
```

Its shown the `key` and `value` as `undefined: undefined`

What's goes wrong in the script?

Comment: I see not "key" and "value" properties in your object. I see item.pid, item.category, item.title, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should access the correct **`properties`** such as **`pid,category`** etc of response,

```
  var items = data.blog.map(function (item) {
            return item.pid + ': ' + item.category;
 });
```